# prepend a div and hide it with this object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="newsSubmit"><b>Add random snippet</b></div>

<script>
  $("#newsSubmit").click(function(){
   $("body").append("<div class='lol'>Ok, DELETE this snippet (click here)</div>");
  });

  $(".lol").click(function(){
   $(this).fadeOut();
  });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apzdt/6/

How can I fix it? It's not working

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/apzdt/7/

change `mootools` to `jquery` and `.click()` to `.live('click')`

Comment: as I said, use my one. use .live

Comment: If I helped you, please help me: **[accept my answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6V5xR.gif)** (click on that link if you're not sure how to do so)